# How should I present formatted text with bound data in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to bind the contents of a `TextBlock` to a formatted string that contains multiple data-bound view-model properties. I'm also trying to use the MVVM pattern.

For example, I would like to data bind the text to something like this: `String.Format("{0} / {1}", Usage, Total`, where `Usage` and `Total` are view-model properties.

I've tried using `Run`s, but binding their `Text` properties doesn't seem to work, and the XAML is messy compared to `String.Format`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Usage}" />
    <Run Text=" / " />
    <Run Text="{Binding Total}" />
</TextBlock>
```

I've considered adding an extra view-model property to do the text formatting, but it seems out-of-place; I want the view to contain presentation logic.

How should I do this? Note that I favour maintainable, neat, elegant and organised solutions.

Comment: Could you post some more code - your view model .cs file would be helpful, specifically the sections that declare your Usage and Total properties.

Comment: @ZombieSheep, I don't think the view-model code is relevant. Whether the properties just return constants, are auto-implemented, or properly using `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the result is the same. The problem only occurs when I try to bind to a `Run`'s `Text` property rather than a `TextBlock`'s.

Comment: I just saw your comment on my answer - I was only wondering if there'd been a mistake in implementing the properties but it looks like that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that binding the Text property of a Run control "doesn't work", are you sure you are binding to the correct objects?  (I'm also including the obvious question of whether your properties are declared properly in the view model, but I assume you have checked that and ensured adequately scoped getters/setters).  I use this methodology extensively in a couple of apps, and haven't had any issues.  Are you getting any binding errors in your output window that might help narrow down the cause?

I'd recommend not adding properties to your view model just yet until you are totally sure that you can't do what you want with the view - what if requirements change later and you want to (for example) apply a foreground color colnverter to one of the values?

**EDIT**

I've just put together a simple demo project that shows it working.  In VS -> File -> New -> Project -> Blank App (XAML)
Edited MainPage.xaml and MainPage.Xaml.cs.  Full text from the files is as follows...

MainPage.Xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="RunDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RunDemo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <!-- added from here... -->
        <TextBlock FontSize="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Run Text="{Binding Usage}"/>
            <Run Text=" / "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Total}"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <!-- ...to here. -->
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage,xaml.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace RunDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
        /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            DataContext = new DummyViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class DummyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int total = 15;
        private string usage = "ten";
        public int Total
        {
            get
            {
                return total;
            }
            set
            {
                total = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Total");
            }
        }
        public string Usage
        {
            get
            {
                return usage;
            }
            set
            {
                usage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Usage");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if(null != PropertyChanged)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confident that I'm binding to the correct objects because the bindings work fine if they are applied to other objects such as `TextBlock`s. I checked the output window, and I didn't find any binding-related errors.

Comment: Very strange - I'd be very interested to see what's going on.  Please let us know if you solve the issue.  As I say, I am happily binding Runs' Test properties in my apps so I'm not at all sure what's going on here. :(

Comment: Are you definitely working with Windows Store App projects rather than SilverLight or WPF?

Comment: Added fully working sample that can be added into a new Blank App template app.

Comment: I actually ended up discovering that, as you said, the XAML code in the question *did* work correctly. The problem I had was occurring for an unrelated reason, but I actually forgot what that reason was. (I fixed it up a long time ago now.) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I would add an additional property on your ViewModel as you suggested personally. Your viewmodel will always be tightly coupled to your view, so I wouldn't see this as a bad thing either.

If you really don't want to then you can use multiple textboxes within a stack panel with an orientation of horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StringFormat` property of the `Binding` object to format your string. In your case of course you'll need to use `MultiBinding`.

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} / {1}">
    <Binding Path="Usage" />
    <Binding Path="Total" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `MultiBinding`. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in Windows Store Apps. The question was tagged appropriately, but I didn't mention this requirement in the question body or title, so I've edited it to make this clearer.